Plotting fuctions with domain markers at endpoints
I am trying to plot functions while showing the type of domain at the end points, i.e. open in both ends (<->), closed in both ends ([-]), or a combination (<-] or [->). I have tried experimenting with arrows, but I can't figure out a way to show a combination, where the function is open in one end and closed in the other. My example only has linear functions right now, but I want the solution to hold for non-linear functions as well. My example also has a solid arrow, but I would like an arrow that is closer in shape to the actual domain symbols used in math, i.e. [1, 2 \rangle 
My code thus far
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\tikzset{
  myclosed/.style={>={Bracket[sharp, scale length=1.5]}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!50},
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
    ymin=-3.5, ymax=2.5,
    ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}]
\addplot[<->, blue, thick, mark=none, domain=-2:1] {x-1};
\addplot[<->, blue, thick, myclosed, mark=none, domain=1:2] {-2*x+4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here is an example of what I would like to get as a result, but where the line from (1,2) to (2,0) har an open domain marker at (2,0).


Instead of defining an arrow, define a tip; to change the myopen arrow, you can use a Straight Barb:
\documentclass[margin=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\tikzset{
  myclosed/.tip={Bracket[sharp, scale length=1.5]},
  myopen/.tip={Straight Barb[angle=150:4pt, scale length=2.5]},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!50},
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5,
    ymin=-3.5, ymax=2.5,
    ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}]
\addplot[myopen-myclosed, red, thick, mark=none, domain=-2:1] {x-1};
\addplot[{myclosed[reversed]}-myopen, blue, thick, mark=none, domain=1:2] {-2*x+4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The advantage of tips is that you can also add options (like in the reversed on the blue line); just remember to add {} around the tip specification.
BTW, notice that you can simply call the two tips o and c (they do not clash with other definitions, being restricted to the tip parsing) to make the specification nicer (\draw[o-c,...).

Thank you very much. This is perfect. And thank you also for the extra tip of using o and c, and showing me the reversed trick!
